# best way to return value based on threshold

Tags: python

I just wrote a code in python that returns a certain percentage, based on the difference of 2 variables to a threshold. The percentage goes from 1.0 to 0.5.
What would be a way to get this done faster/cleaner?

```
threshhold_0 = 0
threshhold_1 = 50
threshhold_2 = 200
threshhold_3 = 500


if ml1_pred > threshhold_end and ml2_pred > threshhold_end:

    investment_percent = 0.0001

    #print('END-THRESHHOLD TRIGGERED')
    #print(f'percent of btc investment amounts to {investment_percent}')
    return investment_percent

elif ml1_pred > threshhold_5 and ml2_pred > threshhold_5:

    #print(ml1_pred, ml2_pred, threshhold_5)

    investment_percent = 0.9999

    return investment_percent

elif ml1_pred > threshhold_4 and ml2_pred > threshhold_4:

    investment_percent = 0.95

    return investment_percent

elif ml1_pred > threshhold_3 and ml2_pred > threshhold_3:

    investment_percent = 0.90

    return investment_percent


...........
```

Comment: Where is the difference of two variables? I see `ml1_pred` and `ml2_pred`, but no difference.

Comment: Use a loop, with a dict or list for your threshold values and resulting `investment_percent` values. When looped in the right order, you can use an early return from that loop. It is also easy to adjust things later this way. (With a dict, threshold values can be the keys, return values the values. Just make sure you define the dict in the correct order.)

Comment: ml1_pred and ml2_pred are variables. They change consistently but mostly range from 0 to 3500

Comment: Please produce a working example.

Comment: You've commented on what ml1/2_pred mean. But that doesn't answer my (first) comment.

Comment: difference was meant as in ml1_pred - threshold = difference.